# Regex find a match and take all characters to end of the line

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to find match on a line and then take all charecters in the string up to the line break, knew it but haven't used regex heavily in a while : )

so:

```
[\d]+\s[A-Za-z.]+ Anything to line break
```

Any ideas ?

Thank you in advance

*I'm using .net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match everything but a line break at the end:

```
[\d]+\s[A-Za-z.]+[^\n]*
```